# libgdx scene2d returning wrong label height

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I want to position three text labels at an exact specific point on the screen (in this case on top to illustrate the problem easier). So I have:

```
LabelStyle labelStyle = new LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), new Color(1,1,1,1));

Label textFullSize = new Label("Line 1 of 4\nLine 2 of 4\nLine 3 of 4\nLine 4 of 4", labelStyle);
textFullSize.setFontScale(1);
textFullSize.setPosition(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-textFullSize.getPrefHeight());
stage.addActor(textFullSize);

Label textHalfSize = new Label("Line small 1 of 4\nLine small 2 of 4\nLine small 3 of 4\nLine small 4 of 4", labelStyle);
textHalfSize.setFontScale(0.5f);
textHalfSize.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*0.15f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-textHalfSize.getPrefHeight());
stage.addActor(textHalfSize);       

Label textDoubleSize = new Label("Line large 1 of 4\nLine large 2 of 4\nLine large 3 of 4\nLine large 4 of 4", labelStyle);
textDoubleSize.setFontScale(2);
textDoubleSize.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*0.25f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-textDoubleSize.getPrefHeight());
stage.addActor(textDoubleSize);
```

But here is what I'm getting:
[image: wrong label positioning]

Why is this happening? Why can't getPrefHeight() return the correct height of the label? How can I position labels without that?

Answer (score 0):

When you change a label's scale, its new size is not automatically called until `stage.act()` is called. This is to avoid wasting a lot of computation recalculating the size of everything if you make multiple changes that will affect size.

But you can force it to update its size by calling `layout()` on the label. Then you'll get the proper value when you call `getPrefHeight()`. For example:

```
Label textHalfSize = new Label("Line small 1 of 4\nLine small 2 of 4\nLine small 3 of 4\nLine small 4 of 4", labelStyle);
textHalfSize.setFontScale(0.5f);
textHalfSize.layout();
textHalfSize.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*0.15f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-textHalfSize.getPrefHeight());
stage.addActor(textHalfSize);
```

In general, this is not wasteful, because it will internally mark its layout as updated, so in most cases it won't have to recalculate this stuff in `stage.act()`.

Comment: This has no effect. `getPrefHeight()` returns the same (incorrect) value before and after calling `layout()`.